# Al utilizar if/else en c++ no me aparece lo que quiero

Tags: condiciones

me dejaron de tarea uitilizar if/else para determinar que tipo de triangulo segun sus lados y angulos, pero al poner las codiciones y ejecutar el programa siempre me aparecen las mismas sentencias y quiero saber que es lo que he hecho mal para que no pueda determinar las demas, ya que el programa si funciona no hay errores.
este es el codigo que he hecho:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <cmath>
     using namespace std;
     int main(){
     const double pi = 3.141592,
                 k = 90;
     double P1,P2,P3,        // Vertices del triangulo
     x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,      // coordenadas de los vertices
     a,b,c,                  // distancia entre dos puntos
     theta,alpha,beta;       // pendientes de la recta

     cout<< "\t**Clasificacion de los triangulos segun
     la longitud de los      lados y angulos**\n ";
     cout<< "\n\t >>Ingrese las coordenadas de los vertices: " << "\n";
     cin>> x1 >> y1;
     cout<< "\n\t * P1: " <<"("<< x1 <<","<< y1 <<")";
     cin>> x2>>y2;
     cout<< "\t * P2: " <<"("<< x2<<","<<y2<<")";
     cin>> x3>>y3;
     cout<< "\t * P3: " <<"("<< x3<<","<<y3<<")\n";

     a = sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2)+pow(y1-y2,2));
     b = sqrt(pow(x2-x3,2)+pow(y2-y3,2));
     c = sqrt(pow(x3-x1,2)+pow(y3-y1,2));

     theta = acos((pow(a,2)-(pow(b,2))-(pow(c,2)))/(-2*b*c));
     theta = theta*180/pi;
     alpha = acos((pow(b,2)-(pow(a,2))-(pow(c,2)))/(-2*a*c));
     alpha = alpha*180/pi;
     beta = 180-theta-alpha;

    cout<< "\n\t >>Distancia entre los puntos:\n ";
    cout<< "\n\t Lado a: " << a << "\n\t Lado b: 
    " << b << "\n\t Lado c: " <<    c<<"\n";
    cout<< "\n\t >>Angulos:\n ";
    cout<< "\n\t θ: " << theta <<"\n"<<
    "\t α: " << alpha <<"\n"<< "\t β: " << beta <<"\n";
    cout<< "\n\t >>Tipo de triangulo: " <<"\n";

    if(a == b == c)
         cout<< "\n El triangulo es: equilatero ";
    else if(a != b != c)
         cout<< "\n El triangulo es escaleno ";
    else
        cout<< "\n El triangulo es isosceles ";
    if(theta<90||alpha<90||beta<90)
        cout<< "\n El triangulo es acutangulo ";
    else if(alpha==90||theta==90||beta==90)
        cout<< "\n\t El triangulo es rectangulo ";
    else
        cout<< "\n\t El triangulo es obtusangulo ";

return 0;    
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya probaste añadiendo las llaves y cierre de cada if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
if(a == b && b == c)
       cout<< "\n El triangulo es: equilatero ";
else if(a != b && b != c && a != c)
     cout<< "\n El triangulo es escaleno ";
else
    cout<< "\n El triangulo es isosceles ";

if(alpha==90||theta==90||beta==90)
    cout<< "\n\t El triangulo es rectangulo ";      
else if(theta>90||alpha>90||beta>90)
    cout<< "\n\t El triangulo es obtusangulo ";
else
    cout<< "\n El triangulo es acutangulo ";
```

Y ahora te explico:

a) `if(a == b == c)` no funciona como esperas, comparando los tres valores, sino que compara los dos primeros y, ese `verdadero` o `falso` que obtiene, lo compara con `c`. Esto se resuelve comparando primero `a` con `b`, después `b` con `c` y, por la propiedad transitiva, si las dos primeras con ciertas, `a==c` también será verdadero

b) El orden de las comparaciones es importante, debes empezar por la más restrictiva. En tu caso es obtusángulo (o rectángulo) pues, como no pueden sumar más de 180º, si tiene un ángulo obtuso, el triángulo ya no puede ser rectángulo: 91+90=181. Acutángulo será si no lo es de cualquiera de las otras clases, porque TODOS sus ángulos deben ser agudos.

c) Por las llaves `{}` no te preocupes, mientras sepas a quién pertenece cada `else` y tenga claro que sólo tendrá en cuenda una única instrucción, no tendrás problema. Ante la duda, úsalas. En mi opinión, son más importantes las tabulaciones: los compañeros y tu yo del futuro, las agradecen.

Comment: cuando el triangulo es rectangulo aun me aparece el mensaje que es rectangulo que sucede?

Comment: Hola Víctor, no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: perdon, cuando el triangulo es rectangulo me muestra el mensaje de que es obtusangulo no se donde esta el error

Answer (score 0):

no me fijé bien de todas las cuentas que sacaste pero prueba cambiando el condicional de esta manera: `if (a == b && b == c)`
 Porque al parecer estás generando un conflicto allí . Éxitos